# How to get notified when a new job in redis is added

Tags: node.js, kue

I am implementing [redis](http://redis.io/) queue with [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) in my [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) app. I have an API which will add email `jobs` to an `email queue`. Is it a good practice to have a cron job listening to the `redis` `email queue` for new jobs or is there a way by which an event is fired from the `node.js` app when a new email `job` is entered and caught from a separate `node.js` app to process it. I'm a little confused on the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are good events supplied by Kue:

https://github.com/Automattic/kue#queue-events

```
queue.on('job enqueue', function(id, type){
  console.log( 'Job %s got queued of type %s', id, type );
});
```

However, it seems from your question that you don't only want to be notified of jobs in the queue but instead you want to **process** these jobs as they are enqueued.

https://github.com/Automattic/kue#processing-jobs

```
queue.process('email', function(job, done){
  // do something with job.data
  // callback to done
  email(job.data.to, done);
});
```